# My application uses AWT even though the jar its built on uses Swing. Why?

Tags: java, macos, swing, awt, .app

I have an application that I compiled into an executable jar file, lets say app.jar. When I run this, it looks like a native mac application, what looks very reminiscent of my limited knowledge of swing. Then, I used [Java's appBundler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) to bundle the jar file following the instructions listed, and suddenly the same project will launch looking like an AWT application instead (much blurrier, more pixelated).

In addition to this, the jar file will launch with the working directory as the parent folder (If it's `dist/app.jar`, `dist` is the working directory) while the application will show my user drive (`~`) as the working directory.

Heres an example program that I am bundling:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
        }
    });
  }
}
```

The jar looks like swing and says "/Users/me/Documents/app/dist/." while the app looks like AWT and says "/Users/me/."

Any reason for the switch? I'd much prefer swing and the directory of the jar file, but I need it to be formatted as an application.

Comment: Take a look at [How to set the look and feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) and make sure you've initialise your application to use the system look and feel

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing the look and feel to use the "system" look and feel...

```
public void run() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    //...
```

This should ensure that it overrides any other settings...

Take a look at [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for more details

Comment: I tried to add this to the above program, and after bundling the same problem occurred. There was no noticeable difference.

Comment: Then something else is wrong. Under Mac OS, the default look and feel seems to be set to use the system look and feel. It's possible that your code is altering the look and feel internally

Comment: But the above code in my question is all I'm running! Does that change it?

Comment: The code in Your question does not change the look and feel

Comment: I mean that I added your code (`try{...} catch {...}`) directly to my code, yet the same problem arose.

Comment: *"I'd much prefer swing and the directory of the jar file"* - The directory is irrelevant. *"while the application will show my user drive (~) as the working directory"* This seems to be how the AppBundler (or at least the code that launchers your app) works, don't think there is anything you can do

Comment: When I run your code, either from the IDE, commandline or app bundle, I don't seem to have a problem...(from an UI perspective)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's something weird with AppBuilder.
Have you tried building your jar just with the jar command?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: I build the jar using ant. Thats why the jar works fine! and the jar command works but tends to make the jar executable only through the command line. I'm making the app for non-computer people, so I cant ask that of them. Also, this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Good call. My bad. 
I did find [this blog post](http://www.intransitione.com/blog/take-java-to-app-store/) from about 2 years ago talking about Swing/AWT issues with AppBuldler.

It looks like back then Swing and AWT application just wouldn't open because of a dependency on the freetype lib.
Perhaps that's been fixed, but there's still an issue.
The guy that wrote this blog post looks like he's made fork of the AppBundler. Maybe you can give that a shot...

Comment: I tried it, it still wont run properly. It looks like the fork was made for issues with it altogether crashing, but thats not the problem I'm having. It runs, just improperly.